# Set Item Level Permissions on a SharePoint online library using CSOM PowerShell

Tags: powershell, document-library, csom, online

I'm using this script below to upload a file or multiple files in a document library in sharepoint online.  I would like to set only the 'read' permission so that only one specific user can read (see) the file.

How can I set the 'read' permission for a specific domain user first and then upload the file?

Why? -> I want to make a folder "paychecks 2019" and then upload a paycheck and set the permissions so that the workers can only see their personal paycheck.

I can also create a folder for each worker and set the read permission on folder level but I prefer to give them all access to "paychecks 2019" and give them permissions on file level during uploading.

---

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds


$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocLibName)
$Context.Load($List.RootFolder)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$TargetFolder = $Context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $FolderName);


Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder -File))
{
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
$Upload =  $TargetFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot grant a permission on a file before uploading it as there is nothing to set the permission on before the file has been uploaded, unless you have a container (folder). In any case, if you upload the file and then set the permission, the file would only be visible for a second or so, and probably just a fraction of a second.

If you use folders, you can create the folder, set the read only permission and then upload the file. You can hide that fact that you are using folders by creating a default view that sets "Show all items without folders" so users only see a single list of files (but still secured by the folders they were uploaded to).